# Filtering query using CoreData through UISearchBar

Tags: swift, database, core-data, filter, uisearchbar

I used `CoreData` to gather my data, it has 2 `entities` which are category and items, each category has a many relationship with items, and I have a `UISearchBar` to filter data as well, however whenever I attempt to search it shows every single item in the Item entity, what I need to do it to show only items related to the category itself so that it shows items to the category I select, my code shown above.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

  let request : NSFetchRequest <Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS [cd] %@", searchBar.text!)
   request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
   do {
       itemArray = try context.fetch(request)
   } catch {
        print(error)
    }
   tableView.reloadData()

   if searchBar.text?.count == 0 {
       loadItems()
       tableView.reloadData()
      DispatchQueue.main.async {
          searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
       }
    }
}
```

This is the code that shows me every single item on the Item entity, I guess it might have something to do with the request I initialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the category information to the predicate. There must be an unique way to identify the category. In the code below it's assumed that there is a relationship `category` in `Item` which has a `name` attribute and a variable `category` in the class which contains the current category

And it's bad practice to check for empty search string at the end of the method.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    guard let searchText = searchBar.text else { return }
    if searchText.isEmpty {
       loadItems()
       tableView.reloadData()
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
          searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
       }
    } else {
       let request : NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
       request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS [cd] %@ AND category.name == %@", searchText, category.name)
       request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
       do {
           itemArray = try context.fetch(request)
       } catch {
           print(error)
       }
       tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man it worked perfectly !! but can I ask you why is it a bad practice? I am a beginner myself and I would be thankful if you tell me

Comment: You will perform the fetch regardless of the length of the search text. My code first checks for empty string (by the way `isEmpty` is much better than `.count == 0`) and then with an `else` clause loads all data or performs the fetch.